# Is it possible for DefaultMessageListenerContainer to create n number of JMS sessions each from a different JMS connections

Tags: spring-jms

I have set up my DefaultMessageListenerContainer with implementation of javax.jms.MessageListener wired to it.

I use MQQueueConnectionFactory wired to cachingconnectionFactory. Have set cacheconsumers to true at DefaultMessageListenerContainer and have set sessionCacheSize to be equivalent to number of concurrentconsumers.

I see that , when concurrentconsumers is set to 10 , ten JMS sessions are created from a single JMS Connection. Is there a way to create the JMS sessions from 10 different JMS connections?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

Not when using the caching connection factory, it is a subclass of `SingleConnectionFactory`; use the vendor connection factory directly if you want separate connections. Why do you want/need separate connections anyway?

It is generally not necessary to use a CCF with a listener container because the sessions are long-lived, and, in any case, caching consumers can cause issues if you use variable concurrency.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21984319/why-defaultmessagelistenercontainer-should-not-use-cachingconnectionfactory/21989895#21989895) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: I use spring integration as i have explained in this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671299/how-is-jms-session-handled-in-a-flow-containing-inbound-adapter-outbound-adapte . Today, i measured the performance between IBM MQ jms implementation and my new implementation of spring Integration for IBM MQ. The difference looks huge and i am in need of to improve perofrmance of my application in Spring integration.Thought this might help in improving the preformance. Can you please suggest.